# Does Akka Tcp support full-duplex communication?

Tags: multithreading, scala, sockets, tcp, akka

I've modified Echo server from https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-docs/rst/scala/code/docs/io/EchoServer.scala#L96

```
case Received(data) =>
  connection ! Write(data, Ack(currentOffset))
  log.debug("same {}", sender.eq(connection)) // true
  buffer(data)
```

That means incoming and outgoing messages are handled by the same actor. So a single working thread(that takes messages from a mailbox) will process read and write operations.

In "classical" world I can create one thread to read from a socket and another for a writing and get simultaneous communication.

Comment: sockets are bidirectional, but you cannot read and write at the same time using different threads. They are not thread safe. But do they support full duplex ? Yes they do.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx socket is thread safe. Java socket has methods to get InputStream and OutputStream and it's safe to work with them through different threads.

Comment: There is a difference between a socket and a socket class! Sockets are not thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka remoting allows you to use pluggable transport implementations, so you can chose how TCP or any other transport protocol is implemented. By default you get `enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]`.

TCP is a full-duplex protocol. Sockets support full-duplex. So nothing stops you on the transport layer.

Final thing to verify if application layer, i.e. Akka remoting can support full-duplex. Every message Akka receives will be forwarded to destination actor. We know obviously that message handling is asynchronous, so while one actor is processing one message another actor can send or receive messages as long as your transport protocol allows it (which it does in this case).

However, message processing in a single actor is synchronous: any given actor can only send or receive a message at one point in time. This means that if you are sending messages via `connection` while Akka remoting is also receiving messages destined to your actor those received messages will get queued in the actor message queue. Akka remoting will be able to send and receive at the same time, but your actor will go through it's queue as normal: pop, process, [send], rinse and repeat.

Getting back to your question: **you can expect Akka to do asynchronous send/receive over TCP for you**. You don't work with a socket directly when using Akka Remoting. Instead, Akka (netty) runs a channel selector and asynchronously receives TCP messages and sends them to observers/callbacks - internal to Akka. Those get converted to Akka application messages and sent to your actor (added to the queue).

Comment: Mentioned sample uses akka.io package that has no dependency on netty http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.10/scala/io.html. May be  I should rephrase my question. Single actor that handles Read and Write messages(I've checked it's the sample) result in potential bottleneck vs traditional reading and writing thread approach.

Comment: I think it's best to ask a new question. Akka IO is a completely different question. Please change the title of this question back to what it was so my answer still makes sense and ask a new one. Thanks