# Does Akka.IO Tcp has a bottleneck in bidirectional communication?

Tags: multithreading, scala, sockets, tcp, akka

**EDIT: This is a duplicate of [Does Akka Tcp support full-duplex communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056806/does-akka-tcp-support-full-duplex-communication)** (please don’t ask the same question multiple times, the same goes for duplicating on mailing lists, this wastes the time of those who volunteer their help, reducing your chances of getting answers in the future)

---

I've modified Echo server from https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-docs/rst/scala/code/docs/io/EchoServer.scala#L96

```
case Received(data) =>
  connection ! Write(data, Ack(currentOffset))
  log.debug("same {}", sender.eq(connection)) // true
  buffer(data)
```

That means incoming and outgoing messages are handled by the same actor. So a single working thread(that takes messages from a mailbox) will process read and write operations. Looks like a potential bottleneck.

In "classical" world I can create one thread to read from a socket and another for a writing and get simultaneous communication.

**Update**
Discussion in google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-dev/mcs5eLKiAVQ

Comment: What makes you think only one thread handles the actual, low-level connection?

Comment: A single thread handles messages from actor's mailbox(I'll give you a link to a documentation if you like). Probably the thread doesn't consume a lot of cycles to handle a message, but anyway it's a potential bottleneck vs reading and writing thread approach.

Comment: There is no bottleneck, if the buffers are full/empty at TCP level it will either block at send or receive. If you don't want this you need to use select to check if a socket is writable or readable.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a single Actor that either reads or writes at any given point in time, each of these operations takes very few cycles since it only occurs when there are data to be read or buffer space available to be written to. The system call overhead of ~1µs means that with the default buffer sizes of 128kiB you should be able to transfer up to 100GiB/s in total, which sure is a bottleneck but probably not today and in practice (this roughly coincides with typical CPU memory bandwidth, so more data rate is currently impossible anyway). Once this changes we can split the reading and writing responsibilities between different selectors and wake up different Actors, but before doing that we’ll need to verify that there actually is a measurable effect.

The other question that needs answering is which operating system kernels actually allow concurrent operations on a single socket from multiple threads. I have not researched this yet, but I would not be surprised to find that fully independent locking will be hard to do and there might not (yet) be a reason to expend that effort.

Comment: There's another discussion with almost the same arguments in the google group. I prefer to continue there. Additional 2 cents, all you said is true(I haven't seen measurements for message processing overhead in akka, but anyway ~1µs more that enough), but the issue could be in the latency. If a mailbox contains 1k write msgs it will add additional 1 ms for read operation.  That might be an issue for a "local" communication where ping < 1ms. But my original question was why have you decided to introduce additional restriction?